# Python: Linking Lists Together

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, python-itertools

Suppose I have a list where each index is either a name, or a list of rooms the preceding name index reserved.

```
[["Bob"],["125A, "154B", "643A"],["142C", "192B"], ["653G"], 
["Carol"], ["95H", 123C"], ["David"], ["120G"]]
```

So in this case, Bob has the rooms: 125A, 154B, 643A, 152C, 192B, and 653G reserved, etc.

How do I construct a function which would make the above into the following format:

```
[["Bob", "125A, "154B", "643A", "142C", "192B", "653G"], ["Carol"...
```

Essentially concatenating [name] with all the [list of room reservations], until the next instance of [name]. I have a **function** which takes a list, and returns `True` if a list is a name, and `False` if it is a list of room reservations, so effectively I have:

`[True, False, False, False, True, False, True False]` for the above list, but not sure how that would help me, if at all. Assume that if a list contains names, it only has one name.

Comment: Try to create a more coherent data structure. As a rule of thumb, always avoid storing elements of different type or meaning into the same list. Instead, use a lists of lists, or dictionaries.

Comment: I would if I could, but this is something I was given, not something I willingly created lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following method

```
def is_name(x):
  return # if x is a name or not
```

a simply and short solution is to use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

---

**Example:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

def do_it(source):
  dd = defaultdict(lambda: [])
  for item in sum(source, []): # just use your favourite flattening method here
    if is_name(item):
      name = item
    else:
      dd[name].append(item)
  return [[k]+v for k,v in dd.items()]

for s in do_it(l):
  print s
```

---

**Output:**

> ['Bob', '125A', '154B', '643A', '142C', '192B', '653G']
>   ['Carol', '95H', '123C']
>   ['David', '120G']

---

**Bonus:**

This one uses a generator for laziness

```
import itertools 

def do_it(source):
  name, items = None, []
  for item in itertools.chain.from_iterable(source):
    if is_name(item):
      if name: 
        yield [name] + items
        name, items = None, []
      name = item
    else:
      items.append(item)
  yield [name] + items
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll preface this by saying that I strongly agree with @uʍopǝpısdn's suggestion. However if your setup precludes changing it for some reason, this seems to work (although it isn't pretty):

```
# Original list
l = [["Bob"],["125A", "154B", "643A"],["142C", "192B"], ["653G"], ["Carol"], ["95H", "123C"], ["David"], ["120G"]]
# This is the result of your checking function
mapper = [True, False, False, False, True, False, True, False]

# Final list
combined = []

# Generic counters
# Position in arrays
i = 0
# Position in combined list
k = 0

# Loop through the main list until the end.
# We don't use a for loop here because we want to be able to control the
# position of i.
while i < len(l):
  # If the corresponding value is True, start building the list
  if mapper[i]:
    # This is an example of how the code gets messy quickly
    combined.append([l[i][0]])
    i += 1
    # Now that we've hit a name, loop until we hit another, adding the
    # non-name information to the original list
    while i < len(mapper) and not mapper[i]:
      combined[k].append(l[i][0])
      i += 1

    # increment the position in our combined list
    k += 1


print combined
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the function which takes a list and returns True or False based on whether list contains name or rooms is called containsName() ...

```
def process(items):
  results = []
  name_and_rooms = []
  for item in items:
    if containsName(item):
      if name_and_rooms:
        results.append(name_and_rooms[:])
        name_and_rooms = []
      name_and_rooms.append(item[0])
    else:
      name_and_rooms.extend(item)
  if name_and_rooms:
    results.append(name_and_rooms[:])
  return results
```

This will print out name even if there are no list of rooms to follow, e.g. [['bob'],['susan']].

Also, this will not merge repeated names, e.g. [['bob'],['123'],['bob'],['456']].  If that is desired, then you'll need to shove names into a temporary dict instead, with each room list as values to it.  And then spit out the key-values of the dict at the end.  But that on its own will not preserve the order of the names.  If you care to preserve the order of the names, you can have another list that contains the order of the names and use that when spitting out the values in the dict.

Answer (score 0):

Really, you should be using a `dict` for this. This assumes that the order of lists doesn't change (the name is always first).

As others suggested you should re-evaluate your data structure.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> li_combo = list(chain.from_iterable(lst))
>>> d = {}
>>> for i in li_combo:
...    if is_name(i):
...       k = i
...    if k not in d:
...       d[k] = []
...    else:
...       d[k].append(i)
... 
>>> final_list = [[k]+d[k] for k in d]
>>> final_list
[['Bob', '125A', '154B', '643A', '142C', '192B', '653G'], ['Carol', '95H', '123C'], ['David', '120G']]
```

Answer (score 0):

**reduce** is your answer. Your data is this:

```
l=[['Bob'], ['125A', '154B', '643A'], ['142C', '192B'], ['653G'], ['Carol'], ['95H', '123C'], ['David'], ['120G']]
```

You say you've already got a function that determines if an element is a name. Here is my one:

```
import re
def is_name(s):
  return re.match("[A-z]+$",s) and True or False
```

Then, using reduce, it is a one liner:

```
reduce(lambda c, n: is_name(n[0]) and c+[n] or c[:-1]+[c[-1]+n], l, [])
```

Result is:

```
[['Bob', '125A', '154B', '643A', '142C', '192B', '653G'], ['Carol', '95H', '123C'], ['David', '120G']]
```